# OperationFailure: Ошибка аутентификации при вставке в коллекцию MongoDB, несмотря на правильные учетные данные

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

У меня есть база данных MongoDB, и я пытаюсь добавить кое-что из Colaboratory Notebook:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://test:<mypassjeje>@<unique identifier>.mongodb.net/<dbnamejojo>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
fragrance = db.fragrance_db
```

Я заменил  паролем для тестового пользователя и  именем базы данных, которая будет использоваться подключениями по умолчанию.

Но когда я пытаюсь вставить что-то:

```
fragrance.insert_one(perfume)
```

Он возвращает:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationFailure                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-d831294ab74e> in <module>()
     46         count += 1
     47 
---> 48 __main__()

19 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py in _check_command_response(response, max_wire_version, msg, allowable_errors, parse_write_concern_error)
    166             msg = msg or "%s"
    167             raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
--> 168                                    max_wire_version)
    169 
    170 

OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Я также пытаюсь с `&authSource=admin` в конце:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://test:<mypassjeje>@<unique identifier>.mongodb.net/<dbnamejojo>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin")
```

но он возвращает ту же ошибку:

```
OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Comment: Вы добавили IP в "IP Access List"?